# Mysqli num rows not working

Tags: php

I have a fairly basic script (i'm used to mysql but i'm moving to mysqli)

```
<?php
include("../includes/functions.php");
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
$debugMode = 1;
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
if (isset($_GET['u']))
{
    // database connection
    $c = mysqli_connect("localhost", "xxx", "xxx", "xxx");

    // initial query to check if the domain is already in the database
    $q = $c->query("SELECT * FROM `domains` WHERE `domain_name`='".trim($s[0])."'");
    $v = $q->fetch_assoc();
    $r = $q->num_rows;

    // check if the string exists in the database
    if ($r > 0)
    {
        // do not enter if greater than 0
    } else {        
        // vars
        $u = $_GET['u'];

        // DEBUG
        if ($debugMode)
        {
          $fp = fopen('u.txt', 'a');
          fwrite($fp, "$u" . "\n");
          fclose($fp);      
        }

        // do a split of "|"
        $s = explode("|", $u);

        // check alexa rank and update
        $alexa = alexa_rank($s[0]);

        // check connection
        if (mysqli_connect_errno())
        {
         echo mysqli_connect_error();
        } else {        
         // insert query if there is no errors
         $i = $c->query("INSERT INTO `domains` (`domain_id`,`domain_name`,`domain_pr`,`domain_alexa_rank`,`domain_moz_da`,`domain_moz_pa`,`domain_date`) VALUES ('','".$s[0]."','".$s[1]."','".$alexa."','".$s[2]."','".$s[3]."',NOW())"); 
        }   
    }   
} else {    
    header("Location: http://www.site.info/");
}
?>
```

It looks fairly simple, the problem is the count part isn't working, it's still adding to the database duplicate entries, i also tried:

```
mysqli_num_rows($q);
```

This still doesn't seem to work, am i missing something simple?

thanks guys

Comment: You can echo the query and run in the a mysqli client program to check the issue with the query. You can try and catch any exception it is throwing.

Answer (score 0):

You should first be sure your query is right.

So please debug your code like that;

```
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM `domains` WHERE domain_name`='".trim($s[0])."'";
echo "My Query: ". $SQL;
$q = $c->query($SQL);
```

I guess you have problem on your $s variable. If your sql query is right you can check $v variable have any record if $v variable is an array and have value you have more than one record and you can pass to insert statements if not you can add.

Answer (score 0):

ahh thank you! i found my top query was failing because i was using the explode further down the code! thanks guys.